# How can I repeat matrix?

Tags: matlab

Could you help me please to repeat matrix. for example if I have matrix(A) and I want to create a big matrix(B) contains three matrices of matrix(A) in the row and two matrices in the column.

Comment: Check `repmat`. That should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Note that the a quick google for *Matlab How can I repeat matrix* gives the answer to this as the top result. Please try to solve the problem yourself before asking others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATLAB function `repmat` does exactly what you need:

```
B = repmat(A,3,2);
```

For more details see the [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)

Answer (score 1):

In MatLab, you want to use [`repmat()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html?nocookie=true).

In Python, use the Numpy function, [`tile(a, (m, n))`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).

You should check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724410/515559

Comment: Upvoted as you did provide the right answer, but would recommend you to avoid information that is not directly relevant. (An explanation of how to do it in Python, whilst the asker asks about Matlab). It can be a bit distracting.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, sorry.