# How I can convert this matlab code to python?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I would like to write the following operation from matlab to python(numpy).

repmat(sum(data,2),1,20);

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [What is the equivalent of MATLAB's repmat in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721802/what-is-the-equivalent-of-matlabs-repmat-in-numpy)

I would propose something like

```
import numpy as np
np.tile(np.sum(data, axis=1), 1, 20)
```

`axis=1` refers to the dimension along which the sum is taken. as far as I remember, matlab starts index counting with 1, in python/numpy it starts with 0.

hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For your info is this one : np.tile(np.sum(data),(1, 20))