# Repmat operation in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to calculate the mean of a 3D array along two axes and subtract this mean from the array.
In Matlab I use the `repmat` function to achieve this as follows

```
% A is an array of size 100x50x100
mean_A = mean(mean(A,3),1);                % mean_A is 1D of length 50
Am = repmat(mean_A,[100,1,100])            % Am is 3D 100x50x100
flc_A = A - Am                             % flc_A is 3D 100x50x100
```

Now, I am trying to do the same with python.

```
mean_A = numpy.mean(numpy.mean(A,axis=2),axis=0);
```

gives me the 1D array. However, I cannot find a way to copy this to form a 3D array using `numpy.tile()`.
Am I missing something or is there another way to do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `keepdims` to `True` in both cases so the resulting shape is broadcastable and use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) to broadcast to the shape of `A`:

```
np.broadcast_to(np.mean(np.mean(A,2,keepdims=True),axis=0,keepdims=True), A.shape)
```

Note that you can also specify a tuple of axes along which to take the successive means:

```
np.broadcast_to(np.mean(A,axis=tuple([2,0]), keepdims=True), A.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) is not the same with Matlab repmat. You could refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238227/numpy-tile-did-not-work-as-matlab-repmat). However, there is an easy way to repeat the work you have done in Matlab. And you don't really have to understand how numpy.tile works in Python.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(100, 50, 100)
# keep the dims of the array when calculating mean values
B = np.mean(A, axis=2, keepdims=True)
C = np.mean(B, axis=0, keepdims=True) # now the shape of C is (1, 50, 1)
# then simply duplicate C in the first and the third dimensions
D = np.repeat(C, 100, axis=0) 
D = np.repeat(D, 100, axis=2)
```

D is the 3D array you want.