# Using numpy.ones as indices of an array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I would like to translate a matlab code into a python one. The matlab code is equivalent to the following toy example:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
b = a(:, ones(1,3))
```

It returns

```
a =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9

b =

 1     1     1
 4     4     4
 7     7     7
```

I tried to translate it like this:

```
from numpy import array
from numpy import ones

a = array([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])
b = a[:][ones((1,3))]
```

but it returns the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "example_slice.py", line 6, in 
>       b =a[:, ones((1,3))]
>   IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

EDIT: maybe ones should be replaced by zeros in this particular case but it is not the problem here. The question deals with the problem of giving a list containing the same index many times to the array a in order to get the same array b as the one computed with Matlab.

Comment: That would be `import numpy as np
; b = np.repeat(a[:,0,None],3,axis=1)`.

Comment: To replicate the identical behavior, you need to index. So, something like - `idx = np.zeros((1,3),dtype=int)`; `b = np.take_along_axis(a,idx,axis=1)`.

Comment: `a[:]` does nothing.  `np.ones()` has default `float` dtype.  By `ones` do you want index `one` or `True` boolean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MATLAB code can also be written (more idiomatically and more clearly) as:

```matlab
b = repmat(a(:,1),1,3);
```

[In NumPy you'd write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721802/what-is-the-equivalent-of-matlabs-repmat-in-numpy):

```py
b = np.tile(a[:,None,0],(1,3))
```

(Note the `None` needed to preserve the orientation of the vector extracted).

Comment: Your answer sounds great but it returns [[1 4 7 1 4 7 1 4 7]] instead of the expected two dimensional array. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Just switch 1 and 3 here.

Comment: According to your comment, `b=numpy.matlib.repmat(a[:,0], 3, 1)` seems to be a more elegant solution, right?

Comment: @Aleph: You are right, it always trips me up that NumPy changes the orientation of vectors extracted from a matrix. See edit. Your `numpy.matlab.repmat` solution is good too, I guess, I got error messages using that, maybe my NumPy is too old. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension with [`np.full()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) to create arrays of certain values.

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b = np.array([np.full(len(i), i[0]) for i in a])

print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 1 1]
 [4 4 4]
 [7 7 7]]
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :)

Comment: Yes, I am comparing the different solutions and I will mark one as the answer but all answers seem good! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [568]: a = np.array([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])                                
In [569]: a[:,0]                                                                     
Out[569]: array([1, 4, 7])
In [570]: a[:,[0,0,0]]                                                               
Out[570]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [7, 7, 7]])

In [571]: a[:, np.zeros(3, dtype=int)]  # int dtype to avoid your error                                       
Out[571]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [7, 7, 7]])
```

====

```
In [572]: np.zeros(3)                                                                
Out[572]: array([0., 0., 0.])
In [573]: np.zeros(3, int)                                                           
Out[573]: array([0, 0, 0])
```

Earlier numpy versions allowed float indices, but newer ones have tightened the requirement.

Comment: Nice! Your solution is very close to the matlab code! Thank you!